# Undefined variable Laravel using ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I am using ajax for submitting data in the database but when I hit submit button in the return response "undefined " value I got, and the problem lies in the controller. I am not sure why I got this error. I am getting this error on fname variable and obv other variables too as they all are similar.
**Here is the Controller**

```
 public function save(Request $request)
{
   $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'cnic' => 'required|unique:patients',
    ]);
    
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['success' => false, 'errors' => $validator->errors()->all()]);
    }

    $temppatientId = IdGenerator::generate(['table' => 'patients', 'length' => 5, 'prefix' => '22']);

    $patientid = $temppatientId + 1;

    $query = new patient;
    $query->patientid = $patientid;
    $query->fname =$fname;
    $query->lname = $lname;
    $query->cnic = $cnic;
    $query->contactno = $contactno;
    $query->gender = $gender;
    $query->age = $age;
    $query->dob = $dob;
    $query->city = $city;
    $query->address = $address;
    $query->husbandname = $husbandname;
    $query->fathername = $fathername;
    $query->bloodgroup = $bloodgroup;
    $query->maritalstatus = $maritalstatus;
    

    $query->save();
   

    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'patients' => $query]);
}
```

**Here is the Ajax function**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#save1").on('click', function(e) {

        var cnic = $("#cnic").val();
        
       
        if (cnic == '') {
            alert("Kindly Enter CNIC");
            return false;
        }

        var gender = $("#gender").val();
        if (gender == '') {
            alert("Kindly Enter Gender");
            return false;
        }
       
    



       
        var contactno = $("#contactno").val();
        if (contactno == '') {
            alert("Kindly Enter Contact No");
            return false;
        }
        



        var fname = $("#fname").val();
        if (fname == '') {
            alert("Kindly Enter Name");
            return false;
        }

else{

    $.ajax({
        url: "/save",
        type: "post",
        data: $('#registrationform').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.success === false) {
               alert('CNIC already Exists !');
            } else {
               $("#patientid").val(data.patient.patientid);
               // console.log(data.patient);
            }
        }
  })

}
        
    });
});
```

this is my blade file

```
<form class="form" data-parsley-validate  id="registrationform" autocomplete="off">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-4">
                                    <div class="form-group mandatory">
                                        <label for="first-name-column" class="form-label">First Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" autofocus tabIndex="1"  name="fname" id="fname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" data-parsley-required="true">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="last-name-column" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="lname"  tabIndex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="city-column" class="form-label">Age</label>
                                        <input type="number" id="age"  tabIndex="3" class="form-control" placeholder="Age" name="age" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="country-floating" class="form-label">DOB</label>
                                        <input type="date" id="dob"  tabIndex="4" class="form-control" name="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4 col-4">
                                    <div class="form-group choices" mandatory>
                                        <label for="company-column" class="form-label choices">Gender:</label>
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                        <select class="choices form-select" tabIndex="5" id="gender" name="gender">
                                          <option value="">SELECT</option>
                                          <option value="MALE">MALE</option>
                                          <option value="FEMALE">FEMALE</option>
                                          <option value="NEUTER">NEUTER</option>
                                        </select>
                                     </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4 col-4">
                                    <div class="form-group mandatory">
                                        <label for="email-id-column" class="form-label">Contact No</label>
                                        <input type="number" id="contactno" tabIndex="6"  class="form-control" name="contactno" placeholder="Contact No" data-parsley-required="true">
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-4 col-4">
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        <label for="email-id-column" class="form-label">Father Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="fathername" tabIndex="7" class="form-control" name="fathername" placeholder="Father Name" data-parsley-required="true">
                                    </div>
                                </div>



                                <div class="col-md-4 col-4">
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        <label for="email-id-column" class="form-label">Husband Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="husbandname" tabIndex="8" class="form-control" name="husbandname" placeholder="Husband Name" data-parsley-required="true">
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-4 col-4">
                                    <div class="form-group mandatory">
                                        <label for="email-id-column" class="form-label">CNIC</label>
                                        <input type="number" id="cnic" class="form-control" tabIndex="9" name="cnic" placeholder="CNIC" data-parsley-required="true">
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-4 col-4">
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        <label for="email-id-column" class="form-label">City</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="city" tabIndex="10" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="City" data-parsley-required="true">
                                    </div>
                                </div>





                                 <div class="col-md-4 col-4">
                                    <div class="form-group choices">
                                        <label for="company-column" class="form-label choices">Marital Status</label>
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                        <select class="choices form-select" tabIndex="11" id="maritalstatus" name="maritalstatus">
                                            <option value="">SELECT</option>
                                            <option value="NOT SPECIFIED">NOT SPECIFIED</option>
                                            <option value="SINGLE">SINGLE</option>
                                            <option value="MARRIED">MARRIED</option>
                                            <option value="WIDOW">WIDOW</option>
                                            <option value="WIDOWER">WIDOWER</option>
                                            <option value="DIVORCED">DIVORCED</option>
                                            <option value="SEPARATED">SEPARATED</option>
                                            <option value="UNKNOWN">UNKNOWN</option>
                                        </select>
                                     </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>



                                <div class="col-md-4 col-4">
                                    <div class="form-group choices">
                                        <label for="company-column" class="form-label choices">Blood Group</label>
                                     <div class="form-group">
                                        <select class="choices form-select" tabIndex="12" id="bloodgroup" name="bloodgroup">
                                            <option value="">SELECT</option>
                                            <option value="NOT SPECIFIED">NOT SPECIFIED</option>
                                            <option value="A POSITIVE">A POSITIVE</option>
                                            <option value="A NEGATIVE">A NEGATIVE</option>
                                            <option value="B POSITIVE">B POSITIVE</option>
                                            <option value="B NEGATIVE">B NEGATIVE</option>
                                            <option value="O POSITIVE">O POSITIVE</option>
                                            <option value="O NEGATIVE">O NEGATIVE</option>
                                            <option value="AB POSITIVE">AB POSITIVE</option>
                                            <option value="AB NEGATIVE">AB NEGATIVE</option>
                                        </select>
                                     </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>



                               


                                <div class="col-md-4 col-4">
                                    <div class="form-group mandatory">
                                        <label for="email-id-column" class="form-label">Address</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="address" class="form-control" tabIndex="13" name="address" placeholder="Address" data-parsley-required="true">
                                    </div>
                                </div>




                                <div class="col-6 col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                                    
                                        <div class="card-body px-2 py-3-4">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-8 col-xxl-5 d-flex justify-content-start ">
                                                    <div class="stats-icon purple mb-2">
                                                        <i class="iconly-boldShow"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 col-xxl-7">
                                                    <h6 class="text-muted font-semibold">Patient ID</h6>
                                                    
                                                    <input class="font-extrabold mb-0" style="align-content: center; color:red; "  type="number" name="patientid" id="patientid" disabled>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    
                                </div>



                                {{-- <label>Search Patient:</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <label>Patient ID:</label>
                                <input placeholder="Enter Patient ID" type="number" name="patientid"
                                    id="selectpatientid" class="form-control form-control-sm d2">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <label>Patient CNIC:</label>
                                <input placeholder="Enter Patient CNIC" type="number" name="cnic"
                                    id="selectpatientcnic" class="form-control form-control-sm d2">
                            </div>


                            </div> --}}



                     


                           
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-end">
                                    <a  id="save1"  tabIndex="14" class="btn btn-primary me-1 mb-1">Register</a>
                                    {{-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light-secondary me-1 mb-1">Register</button> --}}
                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-light-secondary me-1 mb-1">Reset</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Why are you sending and saving from a $_GET request? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Kinglish post method is not working any idea how can I send data through the post method?

Comment: Yes well you are using AJAX with a `get` request, use `post` instead, because it is not even reaching the controller method now. As @Kinglish said..

Comment: @geertjanknapen i changed it to post ,still same error

Comment: You need to use `console.log` and `print_r($_REQUEST)` to identify exactly where things are not working.

Comment: Also, I think you want to use `method:"post"`, not `type: "post"`

Comment: @Kinglish Undefined variable: fname", exception: "ErrorException" this is the error i got

Comment: @Kinglish the problem is in the variable in controller as before some changes I was submitting the data to DB.

Comment: @user19704437 update your question with your form code

Comment: @Innovin check, I updated.

Comment: From what I see, none of your variables are being sent to the controller(from your ajax). Comment out the line ```$query->fname =$fname;``` and see if it tells you the next variable is undefined.

Comment: @Innovin nope, next variable also not defined

Comment: Then I was right.

Comment: @Innovin yes, whats the solution?

Comment: Why is the submit button commented out? And what is the `else {` just above the ajax call?

Comment: @geertjanknapen I have used validation to check if that value exists in the database so return with alert value already existed else register the patient and return its patient id, yes i have commented submit button as i am submitting through ajax ,i don't want page to reload on submission so i used anchor.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the F12 tools and heading over to the networking tab, under the networking tab you can double check the CSR under is getting pass along to the app under the 'headers' or 'request' once you've clicked on your jQuery request

You should also be able to see that larval responded with if you click 'response'

It might also be worth checking out the laravel.log under storage provider any more insight to the problem, this normally contains some help hints

Comment: Already did that, got same error